# How to initialize Numpy array of list objects

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to create a numpy array that looks like

```
array([[list([]), list([])],
       [list([]), list([])],
       [list([]), list([])]], dtype=object)
```

This array has shape `(3,2)`. However, whenever I do

```
np.array([[list(), list()], [list(), list()], [list(), list()]])
```

I end up getting

```
array([], shape=(3, 2, 0), dtype=float64)
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983053/how-to-create-a-numpy-array-of-lists

Comment: Why do you need such a structure?

Comment: It is _very likely_ that you _do not want_ a numpy array of lists.

Comment: `np.array` tries to create multidimensional numeric (or string) array, which it can do if all the input lists have a consistent size.  It's only when the sizes differ that it falls back on creating an object dtype array (or in some cases raising an error).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
np.frompyfunc(list, 0, 1)(np.empty((3,2), dtype=object))
```

We first turn `list` into a `ufunc` that takes no arguments and returns a single empty list, then apply it to an empty 3x2 array of object type.

Comment: I've recommended `frompyfunc` as a way of filling an array with custom class instances.  This is a nice use of the idea with standard types like `list`.