# Put a list as element in 2D array in Python numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I've got a 2D matrix from numpy (np.zeros) and I would like that every element of this matrix is a 1D list with 2 elements, this is my code:

```
import numpy as np


N = 3
x = np.linspace(0,10,N)
y = np.linspace(0,10,N)

temp = np.zeros((N, N))

for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        temp[i, j] = [x[i], y[j]]
```

but I've got error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File (...), line 15, in <module>
    temp[i, j] = [x[i], y[j]]
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

And okay, I understand this problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You can also use a 3 dimensional matrix (not sure if this is what you wanted). `temp = np.zeros((N,N,2))`

Comment: Can you provide an example of your expected output? You have two arrays containing 6 entries between them - how would that be mapped into an array with 9 entries?

Comment: Related: [How to create a numpy array of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33983053/4518341)

Comment: It looks like you may be trying to re-invent [np.meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)

Comment: What are you trying to solve?  Do you want a 3d array of floats, or a 2d with actual list elements.  Those are very different arrays.

Comment: @NirF that's work like I want, thanks everybody for help

Comment: Not 100% clear what you're after, but I would try to avoid the loop if possible. Something like: `temp = np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y)).transpose((2,1,0))`

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `dtype=object` when constructing the array and store lists, but that's quite inefficient. It's possible to define a custom dtype:

```
import numpy as np

# custom type of 2 float64 fields
pair_type = np.dtype("f8, f8")
x = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=pair_type)
x[0, 0] = (1.5, 2.5)
```

You can retrieve `x[i, j]` as a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The result you are searching for can be conveniently achieved with [`numpy.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) + [`numpy.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html):

```
np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij'), axis=-1)
```

---

```
array([[[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  5.],
        [ 0., 10.]],

       [[ 5.,  0.],
        [ 5.,  5.],
        [ 5., 10.]],

       [[10.,  0.],
        [10.,  5.],
        [10., 10.]]])
```